# SQL hashtags regex to table

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, tokenize

I have this table:

```
p_id        name      skills
1         Sam       #IT #communication #administration
2         Alex      #French #Trainer
```

i want an sql query to output this

```
  ID     p_fid   skill
   1      1       IT
   2      1       communication
   3      1       administration 
   4      2       French
   5      2       Trainer
```

using postgresql

Thanks a lot

Comment: the problem is i don't even know where to start, i know for sure that i need regexp , but the problem is in SQL you can't use loops and as you can see for one row there might be multiple hashtags, so basically im stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testbed (p_id int4,name varchar(50),skills text);
INSERT INTO testbed VALUES
    (1,'Sam','#IT #communication #administration'),
    (2,'Alex','#French #Trainer');

SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id,
       p_fid, skill
  FROM (SELECT
        p_id AS p_fid,
        regexp_split_to_table(
             regexp_replace(skills, '^#', ''),
             '[ ]+#') AS skill FROM testbed) AS s;
```

Please, have a look at documentation for [Window](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html),
[String manipulation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) and [Array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) functions.

If you really need to have control over the position of your skills, a bit more complex query needed:

```sql
WITH arrays AS (
    SELECT p_id,
           regexp_split_to_array(regexp_replace(skills, '^#', ''), '[ ]+#') arr
      FROM testbed
), series AS (
    SELECT p_id, generate_series(1, array_upper(arr, 1)) i
      FROM arrays
)
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.p_id, s.i) AS id,
       a.p_id AS p_fid,
       a.arr[s.i] AS skill
  FROM arrays a
  JOIN series s ON a.p_id = s.p_id
 ORDER BY a.p_id, s.i;
```

Comment: sorry but what do you mean "have control over the position of your skills" ?
@vyegorov

Comment: @Ali, second query splits `skills` into array and then uses `p_id` + array index to explicitly sort the results via `ORDER BY`. First query implies no ordering, which leaves the meaning of `ID` column unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using MS SQL Server as RDBMS, AND the `skills` column contains nothing else except hashtags and single spaces, you can transform the `skills` column into an XML string and then use SQL Server's built-in XML manipulation functions to split this string into separate rows.

Here is the approach that works for the data sample that you specified in the question.

```
create table people_skills
(
    p_id int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered,
    name nvarchar(200),
    skills nvarchar(1000)
)

go

insert into people_skills (name, skills) values ('Sam', '#IT #communication #administration')
insert into people_skills (name, skills) values ('Alex', '#French #Trainer')

go

select
    row_number() over (order by ps.p_id) as ID,
    ps.p_id as p_fid,
    cast(x.skill_node.query('text()') as nvarchar(100)) as skill
from
    (
        select
            *,
            -- Assuming that there are no leading and trailing spaces and that all hashtags are separated by single space.
            (cast('<skills>' + (replace(replace(skills, '#', '<skill>'), ' ', '</skill>')) + '</skill></skills>' as xml)) skills_xml
        from
            people_skills
    ) ps
cross apply
    ps.skills_xml.nodes('/skills/skill') as x(skill_node)
```

If `skills` column can contain other information except hashtags and whitespaces, then you might need a 'smarter' algorithm for transforming `skills` to XML than the one I used above.